# Klarna checkout returning http_status_code 500 Internal Server Error in response

Tags: php, magento, curl, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to implement klarna checkout using the codes provided by them [here.](https://docs.klarna.com/en/downloads/php)

Implementing the process as is directed by this link ->
https://docs.klarna.com/en/getting-started

I am using the codes inside docs/examples folder, I have placed the library(src folder) in the proper path have provided the eid and shared secret with the store-ID and Shared secret provided by klarna when I created a test account [here.](https://docs.klarna.com/en/testing/apply-for-test-account)

```
// Merchant ID
$eid = 'eid';

// Shared secret
$sharedSecret = 'sharedsecret';
```

I have replaced all the eid and shared scret in all the files and also changed the links in the files properly,

> i.e. example.com to mywebsiteurl.com

```
$create['purchase_country'] = 'SE';
$create['purchase_currency'] = 'SEK';
$create['locale'] = 'sv-se';
$create['merchant']['id'] = $eid;
$create['merchant']['terms_uri'] = 'http://example.com/terms.html';
$create['merchant']['checkout_uri'] = 'http://example.com/checkout.php';
$create['merchant']['confirmation_uri']
    = 'http://example.com/confirmation.php' .
    '?sid=123&klarna_order={checkout.order.uri}';
// You can not receive push notification on non publicly available uri
$create['merchant']['push_uri'] = 'http://example.com/push.php' .
    '?sid=123&klarna_order={checkout.order.uri}';
```

After setting all things properly, when I click docs/examples/checkout.php I get an exception thrown because the server is responding with an error code. The exception is thrown by BasicConnector.php by the code given below,

```
 * Throw an exception if the server responds with an error code.
 *
 * @param Klarna_Checkout_HTTP_Response $result HTTP Response object
 *
 * @throws Klarna_Checkout_HTTP_Status_Exception
 * @return void
 */
protected function verifyResponse(Klarna_Checkout_HTTP_Response $result)
{
    // Error Status Code recieved. Throw an exception.
    if ($result->getStatus() >= 400 && $result->getStatus() <= 599) {
        throw new Klarna_Checkout_ConnectorException(
            $result->getData(), $result->getStatus()
        );
    }
}
```

The error received is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Klarna_Checkout_ConnectorException'
> with message '{"http_status_code":500,"http_status_message":"Internal
> Server Error","internal_message":""}' in
> klarna/docs/examples/src/Klarna/Checkout/BasicConnector.php:212

So my question is this,

1. Am I not sending a proper request, because I can see the request is
   created and no error is given there ?
2. Can I do anything to get a correct response from the server?
3. When does a server responds with an error code when cURL request is
   made ?

Thank you for your time and help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the solution for such a big question was pretty simple.

Setting the eid="200" and sharedsecret="test". Which are the test account credentials.

In my case I was using my original merchant account credentials.

Comment: how am I supposed to know that?

Comment: by asking the support team of Klarna :) really that's a shame. It's written no-where in the documentation that I am supposed to use a default set of credentials for the Klarna Checkout Testdrive.

Comment: I wasted more than a day on that! Their support/documentation sucks a lot if you need to implement advanced Klarna integration and you are using a technology for which there is not a ready API wrapper. I'm using Ruby on Rails and they have absolutely no support on how to write an API wrapper - I have to read C# and PHP code and translate it in Ruby...